# Warning " the app icon has (x) unassigned children " and x keep increasing

Tags: swift, xcode

> warning " the app icon has (x) unassigned children " and x keep increasing

That prevents me from adding any image assets, just to mention I am a beginner at coding, I tried to delete them but they just simply don't get delete it.

I am sure its a bug but I don't know how fix it?

Comment: It means there are image files in your asset folders that are not assigned in the JSON mapping to any asset. Ideally, go through all the assets in the Asset editor and make sure there are no unassigned assets.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Xcode warning, it won't stop your code from running :) If you want to get rid of it, navigate to Assets.xcassets and select the AppIcon. On the view on the right you'll see all of your app icons, scroll all the way down and you'll see four images tagged as "Unassigned children". Select them and hit delete.